# Javascript function parameter in a Template Literal string issue

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-strings

Im learning javascript using webtools of essential webbrowsers (toolset with F12). here is a show up example

```
function sayHello(n){
document.writeln($`Hello {n}`);
}
sayHello("Andy Anderson");
//undefined appears as a result.
```

I expected result as "Hello Andy Anderson" but I got an undefined

Comment: I know your learning so just an FYI, but `document.write` is something you'd avoid in production-ready JS code.  You might be interested in looking into `console.log` while you're learning, or alternatively the DOM APIs for manipulation like `.appendChild`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dollar sign comes before the opening curly brace:

```
document.writeln(`Hello ${n}`);
```

```js
function sayHello(n){
    document.writeln(`Hello ${n}`);
}
sayHello("Andy Anderson");
```

Comment: I'd suggest fixing or eliminating that comment at the end, since it clearly no longer applies. :)

Answer (score 4):

Dollar sign placement is odd. It should be in the string.

```
document.writeln(`Hello ${n}`);
```

The reason you didn't get an error was that the `$` is likely defined as a function in your environment, so it was used as [a "tag" for the template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_template_literals).

Comment: oh! I thought if usage is similar to C#.